# How to get current domain at Nuxt 3 middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I can't use window.location here because it's SSR app.
useRouter, useRoute, and useNuxtApp don't have domain name too.
nuxtApp.ssrContext is undefined.

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to: any, from: any) => {
  console.log("GET HOST HERE")
})
```

Comment: Couldn't you use an env variable? Otherwise, making an express endpoint and getting `request.headers.host` I guess.

Comment: @kissu I have to know host dynamically because I have many subdomains in my app. Can I get host without sending request to express?

Comment: If your app is SSR, what is the issue of sending a call to a local route? What is the actual idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The helper function `useRequestURL()` was introduced with the release of [v3.5.0](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/releases/tag/v3.5.0) of Nuxt. Getting the **current url**, the **protocol scheme**, the **host**, the **hostname** and the **path** is very easy:

```js
const url = useRequestURL()

const currentUrl = url.href     // https://example.com:3000/hello-world    
const protocol = url.protocol   // https:
const host = url.host           // example.com:3000
const hostname = url.hostname   // example.com
const pathname = url.pathname   // /hello-world
```

or if only the **hostname** is needed we can access the object property directly:

```js
const hostname = useRequestURL().hostname
```

Since `useRequestURL()` works on both **server-side** and **client-side** there is no need to check for the `process.server`. The function returns the familiar **URL object** which properties with their descriptions can be found in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#instance_properties).

Nuxt have updated their documentation and the [description of the useRequestURL()](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-request-url) can be found in the Composables section.

Answer (score 14):

I just missed to check process.server before getting nuxtApp.ssrContext. This is the answer to my question:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to: any, from: any) => {
  const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
  let host = ''
  if(process.server) {
    // for 3.0.0.rc_vercions: host = nuxtApp.ssrContext.req.headers.host
    // UPD 27.01.23:
    host = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event.node.req.headers.host
  } else {
    host = window.location.host
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, Nuxt runs on both server and client (isomorphic). Feel free to accept your own question when you'll be able to.

Comment: This no longer works in Nuxt 3 after production release.

Comment: You have to change it to `nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event.node.req.headers.host` to make it work in Nuxt 3, but it still works.

Answer (score 4):

After release I use

```js
useNuxtApp().ssrContext.event.node.req.headers.host
```

instead of

```js
useNuxtApp().ssrContext.req.headers.host
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is way better to use `useRequestHeaders()?.host` to get the same data.